# How to stop .htaccess ReWrite rules affecting Subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(online-shop)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(my)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&year=$3&month=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So the following URLs are rewritten:

`domain.com/home` to `domain.com/index.php?id=home`

However if i look at a subdomain (`cp.domain.com`) i get the following error:

```
The requested URL /home/user/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

so the subdomains are looking in the ROOT directory for the domain however they should be looking in the directory set in the control panel

As soon as i remove this line of code:

`RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

the subdomains start working fine

Comment: If **subdomains are looking in the ROOT directory** that means subdomains are not rightly setup

Comment: check my update. thats not right

Comment: Your update has no additional info. There is no mention of the subdirectory where these subdomains should be pointing to. It is better you provide `VirtualHost` config for main and sub domain to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restrict last rule to only work for main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: how would i do the domain if it was in format `www.domain-uk.net`

Comment: First condition would be: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain-uk\.net$ [NC]`

Comment: this still doesnt seem to be working. it seems like the `RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags)` and `RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)` do not work with the last rule. if i remove either the last rule or the other two rules, the sub domains work fine

Comment: You will need to provide `VirtualHost` config for main and sub domain from your Apache config.